# ONVIF PullPointSubscriptionClient.PullMessages

Tags: c#, events, onvif

I'm trying to get event messages from some ONVIF devices. My code is in C#.

On a (Axis camera) device on `EventPortTypeClient.CreatePullPointSubscription` returns:

```
Address.Value: http : / /192.168.8.48/onvif/services
ReferenceParameters.Any.First().OuterXml: <dom0:SubscriptionId xmlns:dom0="http : / /www.axis.com/2009/event">38</dom0:SubscriptionId>
```

So I add the **"To"** and **"SubscriptionId"** soap headers and can get event messages with `PullPointSubscriptionClient.PullMessages("PT5M", 99, Any, out CurrentTime, out NotificationMessages)`

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscription/PullMessagesRequest</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:f243dbe4-b082-4a6c-aa65-8145468fcf3e</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo0zfnhoyh15KqPZwP/IS9H0AAAAAdCoo8EjbCUScx/bG/DGcdXp8kY6WrAJDp0TTtNAtj0EACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-GWt5XP2ogUljZ/fzEJvnX0WhGpx3FV4i/dRnE539OFU=">
        <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">root</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">pjwOOO0hOXtUZyJb6B6Lb0ctRIU=</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">DEE/P1c/P1E/eG9XTT87Pz8/</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-03-02T19:06:54.269Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://192.168.8.48/onvif/services</a:To>
    <SubscriptionId s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.axis.com/2009/event">38</SubscriptionId>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PullMessages xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl">
      <Timeout>PT5M</Timeout>
      <MessageLimit>99</MessageLimit>
    </PullMessages>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But with devices that only return Address.Value's like:

- (DAHUA) Address.Value: 
  `http : / /192.168.8.243/onvif/Subscription?Idx=57`
- (Siqura) Address.Value:
  `http : / /192.168.8.14/onvif/events_service/SubscriptionManager/15000`

I add only the **"To"** soap header, but the `PullPointSubscriptionClient.PullMessages("PT5M", 99, Any, out CurrentTime, out NotificationMessages)` method gives a fault error.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscription/PullMessagesRequest</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:9e28fea7-541f-450e-8ad0-01a210f76aa9</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPozBB+X6a8MJEsKScTDAWhKsAAAAAJ3lo8k+wp0CaILCjmW72gQ39eqv52SBMteWBucAF600ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-IYP/hqttMbWUf7ljIMnByJQv96x2VxajSEnVHBKfLyo=">
        <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">admin</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">o3Nrz8F+V7kLjMunS/JBQKhu5xg=</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">PxtFP2k/Pz8/P2g/Pz8/Bz8=</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-03-02T19:03:36.894Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://192.168.8.243/onvif/Subscription?Idx=57</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PullMessages xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl">
      <Timeout>PT5M</Timeout>
      <MessageLimit>99</MessageLimit>
    </PullMessages>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any help on this?

**SOLUTION:**

```
System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[] { };
System.DateTime CurrentTime;
System.Nullable<System.DateTime> TerminationTime;
List<MessageHeader> lstHeaders = new List<MessageHeader>() { };
var oEventClient = _session.GetEventPortTypeClient();

var oAux1 = oEventClient.CreatePullPointSubscription(
    new onvif10_events.FilterType(),
    "PT600S",
    new onvif10_events.CreatePullPointSubscriptionSubscriptionPolicy(),
    ref Any,
    out CurrentTime,
    out TerminationTime);

if ((oAux1.ReferenceParameters != null) && (oAux1.ReferenceParameters.Any != null))
{
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlElement oXml in oAux1.ReferenceParameters.Any)
    {
        string strName = oXml.LocalName;
        string strNS = oXml.NamespaceURI;
        string strValue = oXml.InnerXml;

        lstHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader(strName, strNS, strValue, true));
    }
}

// oAux1.Address.Value -> the proxy endpoint address
// lstHeaders -> headers to add to the SOAP message of the proxy request
var oPullPointSubscriptionClient = _session.GetPullPointSubscriptionClient(oAux1.Address.Value, lstHeaders);
var oSubscriptionManagerClient = _session.GetSubscriptionManagerClient(oAux1.Address.Value, lstHeaders);

do
{
    oPullPointSubscriptionClient.PullMessages("PT60S", 1024, Any, out CurrentTime, out NotificationMessages);

    foreach (onvif10_events.NotificationMessageHolderType message in NotificationMessages)
    {
        /// Handle message
    }

    var oRenewResult = oSubscriptionManagerClient.Renew(new LIB.Cameras.ONVIF_WS.onvif10_events.Renew() { TerminationTime = "PT600S" });    

} while (_session != null);

oSubscriptionManagerClient.Unsubscribe(new onvif10_events.Unsubscribe());
```

Comment: What is the fault error?

Comment: Dahua gives: "End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out".
Siqura gives: "... stream ...". Not very helpful.

Comment: OK.
The "TO" header is to ignore.
The PullPointSubscriptionClient proxy endpoint URL is the subscription "Address.Value" (and not the "TO" url).

Comment: This was helpful.  I would suggest posting the solution as an answer and then marking it as the accepted answer (this is [encouraged by the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).  I often do not click on unanswered questions but fortunately did this time.

Answer (score 1):

OK. 
The "TO" header is to ignore. 
The PullPointSubscriptionClient proxy endpoint URL is the subscription "Address.Value" (and not the "TO" url).

Comment: I recently found this problem with one of my cameras, please cloud you explain with a few more details how you solved? Hablas español? (yo si)

Comment: Edited question to add details.